# Codeigniter Ajax POST issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am getting an unusual issue and I would really appreciate your help. I am using CodeIgniter and trying to make a Ajax call from a view. The problem is when I select type: "POST" I always get an error saying, POST `http://localhost/scratchcard/index.php/ajax/ajax/create?callback=jQuery1910195569250266999_1365021602115` 500 (Internal Server Error)  in the console.

My view is something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://localhost/scratchcard//images/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/scratchcard//css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://localhost/scratchcard/js/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/scratchcard/js/yui.formalize.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/scratchcard/js/scratchcard.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url" value="http://localhost/scratchcard/" />
    <meta charset="utf-8"><div id="main_container">
    <div id="create_scratch_card" align="center">
        <label id="form_count">Create New Scratch Cards</label>
        <select id="count_select">
            <option value=""> Select the number of cards to be generated </option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
        <br /><p>    </p>
        <label id="form_amount">Amount of each Card</label>
        <select id="amount_select">
            <option value="" > Select the amount of the cards to be genarated</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="50">50</option>
            <option value="100">100</option>
        </select>
        <br /><p>    </p>
        <input type="button" id="create_button" value="Create">
    </div>
    <div id="ajax_result" align="center">
        <img src="http://localhost/scratchcard/images/ajax-loader.gif" style="max-width:100%;" alt="Processing">
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

my ScratchCard.js is like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var url_link=$("#url").val();

    $("#create_button").click(function(){
        /*$.ajax({
            url:"<?=base_url()?>index.php/ajax/ajax/create",
            type:"POST",
            data:{
                count: $("#count_select").val();
                amount:$("#form_amoutn").val();

            }
        });*/
        if($("#count_select option:selected").val().length==0){
            alert("You Must Select a Count Value first");
            $("#count_select").focus();
        }
        else if($("#amount_select   option:selected").val().length==0)
        {
                        alert("You Must Select a Amount Value first");
                        $("#amount_select").focus();
        }
            else{


                    $.ajax({

                type:"POST",
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                data:{
                            count: $("#count_select option:selected").val(),
                            amount:$("#amount_select option:selected").val()
                        },
                        url:url_link+"index.php/ajax/ajax/create",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $("ajax_result").show();
                },

                complete:function(response){
                    alert(response.reply);

                },


            });             
            } 


    });
});
```

and finally Ajax.php:

```
    <?php 
    /**
     * 
     */
    class ajax extends CI_Controller {




public function create(){


        $this->output->set_status_header('200');
    $this->output->set_header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
        $this->output
    ->set_content_type('application/json')
    ->set_output(json_encode(array('reply' => 'created')));


    }
}
 ?>
```

Can you point me to any mistakes made or any solution on how to fix it?

Comment: if your getting a 500 type error your error is on the server side not in the jquery script.  Check your server log to see the exact error or just visit the ajax url in your browser wth hardcoded test data to figure out the nature of the error.

Comment: @John B, I visited the url from my browser and it works showing {reply:created} as it should. It also works when i change the ajax call frm post to get. Is this related to any configuration issue with codeigniter which I missed?

Answer (score 0):

datatype should be json only

```
dataType: 'json'
```

jsonp is for cross domian and your url looks like its in the same domain and for data you can just do

```
data:{count: $("#count_select").val(),amount:$("#amount_select").val()}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, changed to json but still the same problem. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: From the response tab of Chrome get this: The action you have requested is not allowed.

Comment: is your url `ajax/ajax/create` (think it shuld be) `ajax/create`

Comment: I created another Folder named ajax, so yes the url is fine

Comment: 500 internal error is a server side error... check your server if it is bloxking anything

Comment: I am not sure how to check that. But I checked apache and php error log and there is nothing. I also removed all .htaccess from my htdoc folder